# Eclipse Oxygen Not Highlighting Undefined PHP Variables

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I recently upgraded from Mars to Oxygen Eclipse. I do primarily PHP development. The problem is that Eclipse now no longer highlights with a warning when I'm using a variable that was not yet defined.

While researching this issue, I've seen mention of creating a new workspace and then import the old workspace projects into the new one. To test if that's my issue, I created a new workspace, a new project in that workspace and wrote this PHP.

```
<?php
echo $foo;
```

In the old version of Eclipse, the $foo variable would be highlighted with a warning. Oxygen isn't doing that. I have PDT installed. I've looked through the settings, but found nothing that could make is work.

It's validating PHP. If I do this, I get errors reported as expected.

```
<?php
echo $foo
exit;
```

And if I look in the "Problems" window, the error shows up. But the first code snippet does not report a warning in the "Problems" window.

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse PHP never do that. You had separate plugin installed, probably together with Community Composer or Symfony support. Since we move Composer to PDT you forgot about this ;)

Please install PDT Extensions Core from this update site p2.pdt-extensions.org.

I'll move undefined variable validator to PDT in 6.0 (Photon) release after some code cleanups ;)

Comment: It works now. I had issues with trying to do an in-place upgrade with Eclipse as well, so plugins weren't installing correctly. I burnt it down and installed Oxygen fresh and the plugins again, and it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Photon incorrectly flags some variables that are set by reference. Example, in "preg_match($pattern, $sourcetext, $match)" the $match is set by the function and it is rare that it would be defined earlier; yet Photon is flagging it as undefined. We should either have a mechanism to ignore on a per-line basis, or this should be improved.

Comment: You talking about this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532891
For now you can use var comment /** @var array $matches */